# In ArcMap, what are the units of curvature? Degrees/100m?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, curvature

The help function for ArcGIS' curvature tool just says the units are per 100 z units (which in my case is meters). I am not sure what unit per 100 meters it is though.

Comment: It's depends on your source layer and it's coordinate system.if your z units are feet and your x,y units are meters, you would use a z-factor of 0.3048 to convert your z units from feet to meters (1 foot = 0.3048 meter). The esri said "your" z units.

Comment: Yes, all my units are in meters. I am asking if it is degrees/100 meters, or radians/100 meters etc..

Comment: esri doc: Output profile curve raster dataset.This is the curvature of the surface in the direction of slope.It will be floating point type.                                       By default slopes in ArcGIS calculated in degress.

Comment: I've read the ESRI document on it. I am having problems conceptualizing what is changing per 100 meters. For example, in literature by MacMillan he talks about slope profiles as defined by degrees change per 100 meters. What is changing per 100 meters?